# What is the easiest way to assert that a response object contains a specific success message?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I got a function that returns a `redirect` with a success `message` as follows:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    return redirect()->route('my.route')
        ->with('success', 'All objects have been updated.');
}
```

I wrote a feature test to test the functionality of this function.

```
public function test_user_can_update()
{
    $response = $this->put(route('my.route'), [
        'value' => 15
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(302);
    $response->assertSessionHasNoErrors();

    $this->assertEquals('All objects have been updated.', $response->getSession()->get('success'));
}
```

Is there an easier way to access the session and check the success message?

Answer (score 0):

I found two easier ways to check the success message:

```
$response->assertSessionHas('success', 'Änderungen gespeichert.');

// or

$this->assertEquals(session('success'), 'Änderungen gespeichert.');
```

Comment: Super personal recommendation, always use `assertSessionHas`, because if tomorrow Laravel decides to stop using `session` helper and replace it with other function, your test would stop working, but if you use `assertSessionHas`, that should change internally by them, so it will always work the intended way. Also, it is way more readable using it.